# Fail to read data continously from serial com port in windows 7

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port, serial-communication

Here is my code which is basically opening the serial port and reading data from serial port com 5.

` /*---------------------------------- Opening the Serial Port -------------------------------------------*/

```
        hComm = CreateFile( ComPortName,                  // Name of the Port to be Opened
                            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, // Read/Write Access
                            0,                            // No Sharing, ports cant be shared
                            NULL,                         // No Security
                            OPEN_EXISTING,                // Open existing port only
                            0,                            // Non Overlapped I/O
                            NULL);                        // Null for Comm Devices

        if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            printf("\n    Error! - Port %s can't be opened. Please check port is free or not.\n", ComPortName);
        else
            printf("\n    Port %s is Opened\n ", ComPortName);
```

/*------------------------------- Setting the Parameters for the SerialPort ------------------------------*/

```
        DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };                         // Initializing DCB structure
        dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

        Status = GetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);      //retreives  the current settings

        if (Status == FALSE)
            printf("\n    Error! in GetCommState()");

        dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;      // Setting BaudRate = 9600
        dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;             // Setting ByteSize = 8
        dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;    // Setting StopBits = 1
        dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;        // Setting Parity = None

        Status = SetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);  //Configuring the port according to settings in DCB

        if (Status == FALSE)
            {
                printf("\n    Error! in Setting DCB Structure");
            }
        else //If Successfull display the contents of the DCB Structure
            {
                printf("\n\n    Setting DCB Structure Successfull\n");
                printf("\n       Baudrate = %d", dcbSerialParams.BaudRate);
                printf("\n       ByteSize = %d", dcbSerialParams.ByteSize);
                printf("\n       StopBits = %d", dcbSerialParams.StopBits);
                printf("\n       Parity   = %d\n", dcbSerialParams.Parity);
            }
```

/*------------------------------------ Setting Receive Mask ----------------------------------------------*/

```
        Status = SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR); //Configure Windows to Monitor the serial device for Character Reception

        if (Status == FALSE)
            printf("\n\n    Error! in Setting CommMask");
        else
            printf("\n\n    Setting CommMask successfull");
```

/*------------------------------------ Setting WaitComm() Event   ----------------------------------------*/

```
        printf("\n\n    Waiting for Data Reception");

        Status = WaitCommEvent(hComm, &dwEventMask, NULL); //Wait for the character to be received
```

/*-------------------------- Program will Wait here till a Character is received ------------------------*/

```
        if (Status == FALSE)
            {
                printf("\n    Error! in Setting WaitCommEvent()");
            }
        else //If  WaitCommEvent()==True Read the RXed data using ReadFile();
            {
                printf("\n\n    Characters Received");
                    do
                    {
                        Status = ReadFile(hComm, &TempChar, sizeof(TempChar), &NoBytesRead, NULL);
                        SerialBuffer[i] = TempChar;
                        i++;
                    }

                    while (NoBytesRead > 0);


                /*------------Printing the recieved value to Console----------------------*/

                printf("\n\n    ");
                int j =0;
                for (j = 0; j < i-1; j++)       // j < i-1 to ( '0' ), null or  last character
                    printf("%c", SerialBuffer[j]);
            }
            getchar();
            CloseHandle(hComm);//Closing the Serial Port
            return 0;

    }//End of Main()
```

` 
And because of Setting Receive Mask and Setting WaitComm() Event.

(`Status = SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR); 
 Status = WaitCommEvent(hComm, &dwEventMask, NULL);`)

I am receiving values only **once**. As shown in pic.[image: image showing results from device, which is sending data on com 5.]

Please give me any suggestion how can I receive data from serial port continuously. I am not getting this problem is from these functions or because of buffer size. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pleases re-post your output as text.

Comment: The code you have posted is incomplete, but it seems like one-shot reception. You read the first burst and then exit the program.

Comment: My output is value from a temperature measuring sensor. (17:27:21 00:+0029.2 °C NiCr) which is time temperature and thermocouple material respectively.

Comment: #Eugene Sh this is complete code. Rest is includes and initialization.

Comment: Eugene's point is: what your code does after printing the received value is to exit. If you want to keep receiving data your code will have to implement a loop so that after receiving and printing it goes back to receiving again. And I guess Eugene's point about the code being incomplete is that what you have posted can't be compiled to test it because you missed lots of syntax out. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok. I got your point barny... I will check it and come back to later. thanks for suggestion